# Installing TFS on a non-system drive

Tags: tfs

I am setting up a box that will host TFS plus a number of other lightweight services. The machine has a system drive (SSD) and two RAIDed HDDs. I want to ensure that the TFS data is stored on the RAID volume for disaster recovery.

How do I make TFS use the RAIDed volume? Is it as simple as specifying SQL server to be installed on RAID? Or is there more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TFS stores it's data in SQL Server.  So wherever SQL Server hosts it's data files (MDF/LDF) is where the TFS data will be located.

Note: You don't have to "install" SQL to your data drive, you just have to make sure it's configured to place the SQL Server data files there.

If your databases have already been created you can also move the existing data files using SSMS.

[image: SQL Data File Config]

Comment: Thanks Dylan. Is the above screenshot from a client or server OS? Where exactly is that console from?

Comment: That's SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio), looking at the server properties